# UrlFetchApp is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I am calling UrlFetchApp.fetch("www.google.com")

from my chrome javascript code and I am getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: UrlFetchApp is not defined

Anyone know why it is not defined? I thought it was built in.

Comment: Apps Script isn't part of chrome, but it runs against your Google account on Google's servers. https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1224162?hl=en

Answer (score 12):

[URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) and its [UrlFetchApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) are part of [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) - a javascript-based server-side scripting language that allows you to extend Google Apps products like Docs, Sheets and Forms with custom functionality.

UrlFetchApp class is NOT available in client-side javascript, which is what it looks like you are trying to do. You can only use it in server-side Google Apps Script .gs files.

Comment: is there a way to then get data from google scripts using chrome. Is there another function?