# How to set HTML from JIVE response in apps script properly

Tags: html, json, google-apps-script

I've been at this for quite some time trying to understand and apply the best practices noted here on Stack Overflow, but nothing is working.

Scenario:

I've got the proper JSON response from the JIVE api:

```
{subject=GCI - Partner Project Plan - Template, type=file, content={editable=false, text=<body><!-- [DocumentBodyStart:c062b27a-e734-42fb-a146-c2d978fb77da] --><div class="jive-rendered-content"></div><!-- [DocumentBodyEnd:c062b27a-e734-42fb-a146-c2d978fb77da] --></body>, type=text/html}}
```

What my next goal is, is to properly display this response through basic HTML output in apps script.

Code.gs

```
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) { 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .getContent();
}
```

Page.html (same as an Index.html file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far no luck in deploying as a web app, which is my end goal. When I deploy I get a blank web app. Any feedback would be incredibly appreciated here.

Update: when I inspect the web app, I found one error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: UrlFetchApp is not defined
```

Trying to debug this now. What can this mean for Chrome? I use UrlFetchApp for my json response:

```
<script>
 var finalRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.cloudconnect.goog/api/core/v3/contents?count=5&fields=subject,content,links.next,-id,-resources');

  var data = finalRequest.toString().replace("throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';", "").trim(); 

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  for(var i in data){
    if(i == "list"){
     var content = data[i];
    }
    for(var i in content){
     var text = content[i]; 
      Logger.log(text);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Not the prettiest code, I know, I just want to start with the basics first. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Update:

Ok, this helps out a lot:

[UrlFetchApp is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458140/urlfetchapp-is-not-defined)

Any recommendations or suggestions on how to proceed here?

Update:

I've made the changes to reflect Diego's direction. Implementing google.script.run has gotten rid of the errors noted through inspecting the web app in Chrome. However, I'm still not able to see any of the response when publishing. I have a feeling I'm missing something small here, not sure though.

I was reading into this a bit: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service

Seems like it may be what I'm missing...any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Code.gs

```
function doGet(request) { 
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) { 
  var finalRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.cloudconnect.goog/api/core/v3/contents?count=5&fields=subject,content,links.next,-id,-resources');

  var data = finalRequest.toString().replace("throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';", "").trim(); 

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  for(var i in data){
    if(i == "list"){
     var content = data[i];
    }
    for(var i in content){
     var text = content[i]; 
      console.log(text);
    }
  }
}
```

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
    google.script.run.include();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet.html

```
<style>
#root {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 2rem);
  }
}
</style>
```

Andre's advice is solid!

However, now I'm only able to see:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with JIVE. You need to get the basics first. Please review [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) for how to use your `include()`, which you've listed but aren't using at all. Please review [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) for how to call a server function from your frontend (you can't call `UrlFetchApp` from the client-side js code).

Comment: Hi @Diego , I agree...it has nothing to do with JIVE as I've been successful at getting the response I needed. It's just that the JIVE response has html tags in the text content. However, that's something I can work through to understand more on that bit. This was right, as google.script.run was the way to go! Now that I've gotten rid of my errors, I still am not able to see this content displayed when publishing the web app. Any pointers you can give here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the fixes you made, and then we can help with your remaining issues. Please also check to see if there are any errors in your browser console when loading the web app.

Comment: @Diego done. I really appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to return a value from the `include` function to the client-side.

2) To display something in JS you need to use innerHTML property of an element [1].

3) To handle the response from the server-side, you need to use `withsuccesshandlerfunction` [2] if the response is successful or `withfailurehandlerfunction` [3] if there's an error.

4) In your include function you iterate through a `content` variable that should be inside the previous `if` otherwise it'll error.

I tested the below code and it worked. From your code, I can assume you want to display the values from the `list` field. For testing purposes I replace your response json with an example JSON:

**Code.gs**

```
function include(filename) { 
  data = {
    list: {
      a: "1",
      b: "2",
      c: "3"
    }
  }
  var returnData = [];

  for(var i in data){
    if(i == "list"){
      var content = data[i];
      for(var i in content){
        var text = content[i]; 
        console.log(text);
        returnData.push(text);
      }
    }
  }
  //Return data to client-side
  return returnData;
}
```

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="output">Something</div>
  <script>
    function displayData(responseData) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = responseData.join(", ");
    } 
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(displayData).withSuccessHandler(displayData).include();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction

Comment: This makes sense...thank you Andres! It seems to be working now correctly, just one issue ... the actual content doesn't show. Just [object Object]. Have you seen this before?

Comment: Because in your case `text` variable isn't a string as it should be but rather a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). You could use  `JSON.stringify(text)` before pushing the data to the array in order to display it or log the response data you're getting and [learn how](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) to retrieve the string value of a field you may want.

Comment: Thank you so much Andres! This is solid!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have any information or could point me to documentation regarding malformed html by any chance?